# UnauthorizedAccessException During File Transfer

Tags: .net, vb.net, filestream

My file transfer application is working now, transferring files the way it should. But I have encountered another problem which I believe someone here  in stackoverflow can shed some light.

The problem doesn't occur when I transfer a file for the fist time, without any duplicate on the target location or when I transfer the same file again to overwrite the existing duplicate file while the program is running. But when I close the program and then reopen it to transfer the same file again, with an existing duplicate of the file on the target location that was transferred before, the problem occurs.

I get the error `UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path denied`

I don't see this as a user privilege problem because I'm running the software in an Administrator account. But of course, I'm not 100% sure of this. Please correct me if I'm wrong about my assumption.

Any suggestions about this? I believe, I can work through this by using `File.Exist` combined with some codes, but I bet there is a better way to work through this.

Here's my code.

```
'This is where the error occurs; in the initialization of fileStream
'Maybe this has something to do with FileAccess and FileMode? I'm not sure.
Using fileStream As New FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
  FileSharingStatusBar.Panels.Item(1).Text = "Receiving file . . ."
  Do Until TotalData = FileLength
    If ReadBytes = 0 Then
      fileStream.Close()
      FileTransferInterrupted = True
      Exit Do
    Else
      ReadBytes = ClientSocket.GetStream.Read(FileData, 0, FileData.Length())
      fileStream.Write(FileData, 0, ReadBytes)
      TotalData += ReadBytes
    End If
  Loop
End Using
```

Comment: You'll need to pick a better FilePath, be sure it is a full path and selects a folder that you can write to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any other work around aside from changing the file path? I believe my current file path is a full path and can be written without any problems (supposed to be) because its in an administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days, I finally solved the problem for real. I removed `NetworkStream.Read` and `NetworkStream.Write` in my implementation, and replaced it with `BinaryReader.ReadString` and `BinaryWriter.Write`. That way, the filtering that handles the file transfer and logging becomes one, avoiding confusion during the network transfer.